# query to fetch data from has_many through association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sim_employees, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :sims, through: :sim_employees
end
```

in my sim_employees table I have employee_id sim_d and is_local::boolean.

```
id employee_id sim_d  is_local
1    1           2      1
2    1           3      0
3    1           5      0
4    2           1      0
5    2           8      0
```

So now my requirement is

employees/index.html.erb

```
<%@employees.each do |employee|%>

 <%=employee.name%>
 # here I need a query if employee.id  is_local is 1 for all employee than it will show local. If it is a combination of both 1 and 0 than it will show local/std if its 0 then it will show std. Please let me know how I will fetch this data from sim_employees table here.
<%end%>
```

Now I need a query if employee.id  is_local is 1 for all employee than it will show local. If it is a combination of both 1 and 0 than it will show local/std if its 0 then it will show std. Please let me know how I will fetch this data from sim_employees table. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def of_call_type
    call_types = self.sim_employees.map(&:is_local)
    if call_types.include?(true) and call_types.include?(false)
        "Local/STD"
    elsif call_types.include?(true)
        "Local"
    else
        "STD"
    end
end
```

Write this method in employee.rb

In view

```
<%@employees.each do |employee|%>

 <%= employee.name%>
 <%= employee.of_call_type %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: plz guide how do i write this query `self.sim_employees.each do |se| p 'aaaa' p se.sim.is_active end `so i need to check if `se.sim.is_active`  true or falsewith in a query how i will do this

Comment: didn't get your question..will you please explain?